# Which view layout will be better for make an app store clone?

Tags: ios

I want to create a view similar to the App Store's Games tab :

[App Store Games Tab Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlodR.jpg)

I did created a collectionView for "New Games We Love" section and I added featured games collectionView as header section to it.

Featured Games section is working like what I expected but I thought adding other collectionViews to header or footer view of other collectionViews is not a good idea.

I review App Store layout and I think they firstly created a scrollView and then they added every sections as an unique collectionView.

I want to be sure which way is right or what do you recommend ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this with two way

1)add TableView For Vertical Scrolling.and each cell of tableview contain collectionView for Horizontal Scrolling.

ex : your tableview first cell contain newGame CollectionView.second cell contain (Wahat we are playing now).third cell contain play together in AR.you can find this approach implementain here(https://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/want-your-swift-app-to-scroll-in-two-directions-like-netflix-heres-how/)

2) add one CollectionView for Vertical Scrolling and each cell of Vertical CollectionView Contain horizontal CollectionView.

Comment: Thanks   I will try it 